# Kde Plasma Returning to Login Screen Each Time

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde

I'm a new arch user. I do know arch is for people who already know what they're doing but I'm here to learn (have good enough prior experience with ubuntu,fedora).
So I set arch up properly (partitioning, installing base system).
Then i went ahead and installed`

```
pacman -S xorg-server xorg-server-utils xorg-xinit
```

Then I went ahead and installed plasma using pacman (the entire packages).
everything was A-Ok until i started plasma using

```
systemctl start sddm.service
```

The plasma desktop started but whenever I entered my password, it keeps returning to the login screen. I don't know what went wrong, x11 is working as it should since well plasma started properly.
Did I miss something somewhere?

Here are extra details:
Using a BIOS/Mbr system
Using the nvidia drivers (370.X.X)
4GB Ddr3 ram
1 gb Nvidia Geforce (Don't remember which but it's new)
Intel i5 4th Gen proccessor